# Hamburger issue in Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I started a new project in Android Studio and created a Navigation Drawer activity. On creating that activity it added the dependency *com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+* and set the *targetSdkVersion* to 23, which was giving me error. So I changed the *targetSdkVersion* to 21 and also changed the dependency to *com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1* and the error was gone. But when I ran this *Default Activity* I had **2 Issues**.

- 1. The Hamburger icon was not shown, instead there was a back arrow constantly being shown no matter if the drawer was pulled out not.
- 2. When I tried pulling the drawer from the left edge of the screen it came out but when pushed it towards the edge again it didn't go in. The only way you  could put it on was by clicking the Back arrow or by clicking somewhere outside the drawer.

I guess it has nothing to do with dependency etc. so I'd like to know what the problem is. 
(try creating the activity and see if the same happens with you) 
Hope someone can help. 
Thank You in advance.

Comment: be specific please with your question because if you created the project with the navigation drawer activity from studio it should work 

So whats the error you are getting because of that you need to change the version to 21 give it 

I will help you

Comment: It says could not find "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+"

Comment: okay so you did not downloaded the latest version of support library please download it also you requires this 

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Comment: let me know if you got any more issues

Comment: Okay. I'll let you know about it.

Comment: I would again comment , stop bullying new user (-_-) come-on, stop down voting for no reason,  have a problem with such questions.??, type a constructive comment, save it in notepad, place that on your desktop, so whenever u see such questions post that a comment instead of disliking.!  do u fools even know after 4,5 , even single dislikes account may get banned, i am sorry to say these are just crying ones who cannot edit question to get those easy 2 points and giving answer is outta there capability...

Comment: @DeepakTalan did it solved ?

Comment: @DeepakTalan what happned ?